# Update script using Regex commands

Tags: regex, powershell

Created the following PS script to pull data from some reports and dump extracted data into a .csv file:

```bsh
$csvContents = @()

$hashTable = @{}
$count = 0 

Get-ChildItem $PSRoot\NU_*.txt | %{       
      
    Get-Content $_ |
    ?{$_ -imatch 'Percent of memory in use' -or $_ -imatch 'Remaining Space' -or $_ -imatch 'Percent of CPU in use' -or $_ -imatch 'Node Number' `
    -or $_ -imatch 'Generated' -or $_ -imatch 'Client Name' -or $_ -imatch 'Windows Ver:' -or $_ -imatch 'ActiveName' -or $_ -imatch 'node \d+'} | %{
        
       
        If($_ -imatch 'ActiveName'){                 
            $name = (([regex]::Matches($_,'\w+') | select value).value )
            $store = ([regex]::Matches($name[2],'\b\d+') | select value).value  
        }


        If($_ -imatch 'Node Number'){                 
           $NodeNumber = ([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\d+') | select value).value   
        } 
       
        If($_ -imatch 'memory in use'){       
           $memory = ([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\d+') | select value).value      
        }

        If($_ -imatch 'Remaining Space'){       
           $space = ([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\d+') | select value).value       
        }

        If($_ -imatch 'CPU in use'){       
           $cpu = ([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\d+') | select value).value      
        }
        
        
        If($_ -imatch 'Generated'){      
           $Date = ([regex]::Matches($_,'(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(?:\d+)') | select value).value #[0..2] -join '-'                      
        }
           
        If($_ -imatch 'Client Name'){               
           $ClientName = (([regex]::Matches($_,'\s+(\s+\w+)') | select value).value -join ',').trim()
        }

        If($_ -imatch 'Windows Ver:'){       
           $WinVer = ([regex]::Matches($_,'Windows Ver: (\d+)\.(\d+)') | select value).value -join ','                                                      
        }               
           
       
        $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
            STORE          = $store
            DATE           = $Date
            NODENUMBER     = $NodeNumber
            POSTYPE        = $ClientName
            MEMORYUSAGE    = $memory
            FREEHDSPACE    = $space
            CPUUSAGE       = $cpu
            WINDOWSVERSION = $WinVer
        }
       
            
        If($_ -imatch 'Node \d+'){        
            $hashTable.Add($count,$obj) 
            $count++           
        }

      }
}

$hashTable.values.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property DATE | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation  | Set-Content -path "$Reports\$($Store)_$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd)_$((Get-Date).tostring("hh-mm-ss")).csv" -force
```

Example of .csv file:

[image: output of .csv file]

In the POSTYPE column the PCSERVER is showing 0 and I would like it to show 123.  The EPC4 is showing 0 and I would like it to show 155. Any suggestions on how I can do this.

Comment: Are you saying the regex is not working correctly and is outputting `0` instead of the intended numbers? If so, we need to see a sample of the original data to compare that to your regex.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The Regex is doing what its designed to do, in the file the data is being pulled from see example:

Comment: Yes it's outputting 0 which is listed in file -  DEV155 GetInfo: Node Number      0;

Comment: DEV155 GetInfo: Client Name      EPC4;
DEV155 GetInfo: Node Number      0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to overwrite your source data and always use the numbers you mention, you can just add another couple of `If` statements before creating your `$obj`:

```
If($ClientName -eq 'PCSERVER'){       
    $NodeNumber = 123                                                   
}
 
If($ClientName -eq 'EPC4'){
    $NodeNumber = 155
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, do I add these lines withing the PSCustomobject?

Comment: No not within, just before it